# Getting the CIDR block of a set of subnets

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to get the CIDR block of a set of subnets IDs provided a parameter.

```
data "aws_subnet" "target" {
  for_each = "${toset(var.subnet_ids)}"
  id       = "${each.value}"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "registry" {
  vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"
  ingress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["${data.aws_subnet.target.*.cidr_block}"]
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name}"
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
cidr_blocks = "${data.aws_subnet.target.*.cidr_block}"

This object does not have an attribute named "cidr_block".
```

Terraform configuration:

```
Terraform v0.12.24
+ provider.aws v2.55.0
+ provider.template v2.1.2
```

Thanks to whoever can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a splat expression to the values of the map.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "registry" {
  vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"
  ingress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = values(data.aws_subnet.target).*.cidr_block
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the `for_each` argument makes `data.aws_subnet.target` appear as a map value, and the splat operator `.*` is defined to behave as a no-op if it's applied to anything other than a list or set. Therefore expression evaluation here is taking the following steps:

- First evaluate `data.aws_subnet.target`, producing a map of objects whose keys are the strings from `var.subnet_ids`, which presumably look like `subnet-12345`.
- Then apply `.*` to that map. Because it's a map, that produces the same result again.
- Then apply `.cidr_block` to that map, which fails because its keys are the subnet ids, not the attributes of the subnet objects.

To get the desired result here, we can use `values` to disregard the keys and take the values from the map as a list:

```
cidr_blocks = values(data.aws_subnet.target).*.cidr_block
```

Because the result of `values(...)` is a list, the `.*` operator will behave as expected and try to find the `cidr_block` attribute in each of the elements of the list.

Another option is to use a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions), which is a generalization of the splat syntax that works for any collection-typed value:

```
cidr_blocks = [for s in data.aws_subnet.target : s.cidr_block]
```